# При нажатии на ссылку в TextView открывается AlertDialog с WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview

У меня есть CheckBox с ссылкой

```
CheckBox uslovia = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.uslovia);
            uslovia.setText(R.string.link);
            uslovia.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            uslovia.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if(isChecked)
                            sendButton.setEnabled(true);
                        else {
                            sendButton.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Но при нажатии на нее открывает браузер, если указать обычную короткую ссылку формата:

```
<string name="link"><a href="http://example.com/">Ссылка</a></string>
```

Если указать к примеру:

```
<string name="link"><a href="http://example.com/index.php?lang=ru&test=1">Ссылка</a></string>
```

Он ругается на знаки равно "="

Есть ли возможность при нажатии на ссылку выполнить другое действие? Моя задача сделать, что-то вроде как в приложениях делают ссылку на "Условия конфиденциальности" и их перекидывает на сайт или открывается  AlertDialog с информацией

Comment: По идее знак равенства не требует экранизации. как открываете браузер? пробовали скормить в Uri.parse(link)?

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 способа задать ссылку через ресурсы:

1. Экранируем вручную символ `&` -> `&amp;`

   ```
   <string name="link"><a href="http://example.com/index.php?lang=ru&amp;test=1">Ссылка</a></string>
   ```
2. Используем ресурс без экранирования в формате `<![CDATA[]]>`

   ```
   <string name="link"><![CDATA[<a href="http://example.com/index.php?lang=ru&test=1">Ссылка</a>]]></string>
   ```

   В коде меняем

   ```
   uslovia.setText(R.string.link);
   ```

   на

   ```
   uslovia.setText(Html.fromHtml(uslovia.getContext().getString(R.string.link)));
   ```